# Можно ли отследить копирование URL страницы через JS/JQ?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет. Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли как нибудь отследить копирование URL адреса определенной страницы или использования дефолтного браузерного shared (например при просмотре через мобильный телефон в браузере хром есть значок поделиться рядом с URL в адресной строке) через JS или JQ? Например, копирование чего либо со страницы можно отследить событием "oncopy", есть что-то подобное для URL или Shared?

Comment: Сразу вопрос: зачем?

Comment: Ну в частности хочу отследить статистику по активности пользователей, сколько человек поделилось например страницей со статьей. Ну и в принципе интересно возможно ли это вообще сделать.

Comment: Для отслеживания "поделился"  существуют другие инструменты (вы хотя бы банально на текущем сайте посмотрите как сделано).  То, что кто-то скопировал URL ещё не значит ничего. Я могу просто на 20 вкладок раскопировать сайт, чтобы ботом атаковать....это явно не "поделился"))

Comment: "в принципе интересно возможно ли это вообще сделать" --- чтобы что-то делать, нужно определить смысловую и практическую составляющую. То есть,  можно ли батоном отгонять мух - теоретически можно изучать, но вот зачем?))

Comment: Ну я описал выше вариант использования данной функции, знаю что можно получить URL, но вот именно как отследить копирование ссылки или клике по шареду?

Comment: А я вам написал, что подобный вариант использования делается по-другому. Или вы пропустили?

Comment: *" как отследить копирование ссылки или клике по шареду"* --- это уже банальный JS. банальный adeventlistener на клик (а дальше отслеживать статистику переходов по данной конкретной сформированной ссылке)

Comment: Банальный клик на шаред в браузерной иконке адресной строки? Я понимаю клик по элементу DOM, а по браузерной кнопке как?

Comment: ЗААААААЧЕЕЕЕЕЕМ?

Comment: И причём тут какая-то браузерная кнопка и шаред URL?

Comment: "Для отслеживания "поделился" существуют другие инструменты (вы хотя бы банально на текущем сайте посмотрите как сделано)." - скиньте ссылку если не трудно, только не на  подобные дефолтные яндекс конструктор где можно минимум отследить клик по элементу...

Comment: "И причём тут какая-то браузерная кнопка и шаред URL?" - зайдите в браузер хром на мобильном телефоне на любой сайт и посмотрите рядом с URL иконка со стрелочкой, нажав на которую вы можете отправить ссылку в мессенджер и другие действия.

Comment: я написал зачем, я хочу попробовать отследить взаимодействие с пользователем, хочу именно факт действия с URL отследить, в частности, копирование URL строки, аналогично oncopy для текста на странице.

Comment: Повесить при клике на кнопку вот такое: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/share  и использовать то, что там написано, например https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/share#examples

Comment: Спасибо про Shared читаю, в документации написано, что Firefox не поддерживает, для нее хорошо бы отследить например, факт копирования URL